# What is the impact of work done on motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

An object of *mass* $10Kg$ is travelling at a *constant acceleration* of $10m/s^2$. A resistive force has $-50 J$(negative fifty joules) of *work done* on the object.
What is the impact of that negative fifty joules on the object's motion?
In essence, by what value the acceleration of that object decreases?
(Sorry, if you find my question lame.)

Note: The moderation to be honest is ridiculous.
(IT IS NOT A HOMEWORK QUESTION BUT A DEEP INSIGHTFUL PROBLEM ABKUT UNDERSTANDING THE RELATIONSHIO BETWEEN ENERGY AND FORCE!)

Comment: You should read more carefully this site policy in the Help Center. You'll see that your question, in its present form, is a clear example of *homework-like* question.

Comment: But my intention isn't! I want to understand the impact of energy on motion quantiatatively. There are other sites to get solution for homework like question......

Comment: I understand that it is not your intention. But this should be reflected in the way you formulate your question. You may try to reformulate it in more general terms, trying to put in evidence the conceptual issues related to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The "-50 J" work done by the resistive force will decrease the kinetic energy of the body.  This comes from the work-energy theorem. Assuming the body started from rest at the given acceleration, when the resistive force starts operating, it'll decrease the  net acceleration in a way that depends on the force( whether its constant, or variable). This is because the resistive force will itself produce an acceleration in the opposite direction of the initial acceleration.

Comment: Yeah I got it from Betrand's answer. But may you please quantiatatively answer how the acceleration is affected... Feel free to add the missing data.....

Comment: I just want to know the impact of energy/work done on motion!

Comment: How can you calculate the change in acceleration without knowing the expression for force?

Comment: I told na add the missing data. Correct the question and sove it to reach my objective.

Answer (score 0):

$$E_{initial}=\frac{1}{2}mv_{initial}^2$$
$$E_{final}=\frac{1}{2}mv_{initial}^2 - 50 =\frac{1}{2}mv_{final}^2$$
$$v_{final}=\sqrt{v_{initial}^2-\frac{100}{m}}$$
$$v_{final}=9.45 \frac{m}{s}$$

We cannot say anything about the acceleration unless we know about the distance travelled or time travelled, however we can say the object slowed down by roughly 0.55 m/s

Comment: Please update the question in your answer I mean add the missing data and solve for the change in acceleration due to -50J work....